# Allow only lowercase characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I use following code to check if a user input is lowercase or not. I will allow characters from `a` to `z`. no other characters allowed.

JavaScript file:

```
var pat = /[a-z]/;

function checkname()
{
  var t = $("input[name='user_name']").val();

  if(pat.test(t) == false)
  {
    alert('Only lowercase characters allowed');
  }
}
//... other functions
```

But this donot work all the time. If I enter `industrialS`, it will not find that capital 'S'.

I also tried: `/^[a-z]$/` and `/[a-z]+/`. But not working.

PLease help me.

Comment: Start learning regex: `/^[a-z]+$/` Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5wt9S/1/

Comment: You may also want to consider just lowercasing whatever the user enters and using that rather than forcing them to type in lowercase.  You could even do it live while they type so they see it happen.  Much better for usability to teach them, show them and fix it for them than show them an error message.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your regular expression just checks to see if the string has *any* lower-case characters. Try this:

```
var pat = /^[a-z]+$/;
```

That pattern will only match strings that have one or more lower-case alphabetic characters, and no other characters. The "^" at the beginning and the "$" at the end are anchors that match the beginning and end of the tested string.

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp should be:

```
/^[a-z]+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if((/[a-z]/.test(email))==true){//allow the small characters}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me: Add md5 before password like so:

```
$password=md5($_POST['password']);
```

In the database, select users and edit password then change it to the MD5 longtext password.

That way your password will be case sensitive.

Answer (score -1):

Since all you want is lower case letters, instead of just telling the user s/he's done something wrong, I would fix it:

```
function checkname() {
    var disallowed = /[^a-z]/gi; // g=global , i=case-insensitive
    if (this.value == disallowed) {
        //delete disallowed characters
        this.value = this.value.replace(disallowed,'');
        alert('Only lowercase letters allowed');
        //instead of an alert, i would use a less intrusive fadeIn() message
    }
    this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
}
```